# Templates :Name resolution:Dependent types: -->can any one tell some more examples for this statement?

Tags: c++, templates

This is the statement from ISO C++ Standard 14.6.2.1: Dependent types :

```
A type is dependent if it is
— a template parameter,#1
— a qualified-id with a nested-name-specifier which contains a class-name
   that names a dependent type or whose unqualified-id names a dependent type,#2
— a cv-qualified type where the cv-unqualified type is dependent, #3
— a compound type constructed from any dependent type,#4
— an array type constructed from any dependent type or whose size is specified
    by a constant expression that is value-dependent, #5
— a template-id in which either the template name is a template parameter
   or any of the template arguments is a dependent type or an expression 
   that is type-dependent or value-dependent.#6
```

I am unable to understand the last two points?

Can any one give examples for these statements(especially for last #5,#6 )?

Comment: Why don't you read a [good book](http://www.josuttis.com/tmplbook/) on templates first?

Comment: @Prasoon: That guy has a well-earned reputation for avoiding that. He keeps asking very specialized questions, but seems to lack basic understanding on the subject.

Comment: @sbi : I think he should read a good C++ book first (coz [@GMan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/87234/gman) says so) :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working from `1) a type is dependent if it is a template parameter`:

```
template <typename T, int N, template <typename> class My_Template>
struct X
{
```

5 — an array type constructed from any dependent type or whose size is specified by a constant expression that is value-dependent,

```
    T a[5];        // array of dependent type
    int b[N];      // value-dependent size
```

6  — a template-id in which either the template name is a template parameter
     or any of the template arguments is a dependent type or an expression
     that is type-dependent or value-dependent.

```
    My_Template<int> c;           // template parameter
    Some_Template<T> d;           // template argument is dependent
    Another_Template<sizeof c> e; // type-dependent expression
    Another_Template<N> f;        // value-dependent expression
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class T> struct Base{ 
}; 

template<class T, int n, template<class X> class U> struct Derived : Base<T>{ 
    T array1[10];       // #5 

    int array2[n];      // #5 

    U<T> u;             // #6 
    Base<T> b;          // #6 
}; 


int main(){}
```

Comment: Here ..we can return the size of array by using sizof();

Comment: @BE Student: I am not able to understand your question

Comment: template<class T>int f(T){return sizof(T[15]);} is this correct..according to the statement

Comment: I think you mean 'sizeof'. Yes. It is correct. In this case the expression 'sizeof(T[15])' is a dependent expression as it depends on the template parameter T